# Getting the real C++ exception on x64

Tags: c++, exception, windbg

If I'm catching a C++ exception of some kind, and in the catch statement throws a new break exception, will I ever be able to retain the original exception if post mortem debugging a crash dump in WinDbg? If so, how?

I've seen the usage of searching for CONTEXT (0001003f) on x86, but it's not valid on x64.

Comment: Erm, DebugBreak?  Yeah, the catch statement is still in scope.  Try it.

Comment: @Hans The exception object is.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.  You will need to know how to read x64 assembly and find exception record pointer.   From there see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/07/30/10044061.aspx

This will allow you to see the exception object, but at the time the catch statement is executed, stack unwinding has already happened so you will not have the original stack.